# Can't delete postgis

Tags: postgis, postgresql, installation

```
geo2=# create extension postgis;
ERROR:  PostGIS is already installed in schema 'public', uninstall it first
geo2=# create extension postgis_topology;
ERROR:  required extension "postgis" is not installed
```

It seems I'm getting an error that postgis is installed, but when I try to install postgis_topology it says that it isn't. When I try to drop the extension I get:

```
geo2=# drop extension postgis;
ERROR:  extension "postgis" does not exist
```

How can I drop postgis from the public schema so I can add it to my database?

Comment: Are you working with the latest version available from GitHub? There were issues with this extension in the recent past:  https://github.com/appropriate/docker-postgis/issues/2

Comment: how did you install postgis? and on what platform?

Comment: Is this question still current? What PostgreSQL version and what PostGIS version do you have?

Comment: I haven't gone back to figure this out. Can delete the question if necessary.